# How do I change the name of my Apple wireless keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

How do I change the name of my Apple wireless keyboard?

In the file menu it's listed as someone else's. Don't know how it happened but I want to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> System Preferences, Keyboard and Mouse, Bluetooth Tab, Change the keyboards name to something else (can't leave blank)

<sup>([source](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/other-hardware-peripherals/148749-how-reset-name-apple-wireless-keyboard.html))</sup>

Comment: In newer OSX's it is SystemPreferences/Bluetooth, select the device, then lick the setting "wheel" at the bottom, which has a Rename option.

Answer (score 15):

Note too that if this is a brand-new keyboard that you are still charging using a cable, you may not be able to rename it until you disconnect the cable and connect to the keyboard wirelessly via Bluetooth.

Comment: I thought I was going mad, as I did not have the Rename option in the list... Only Remove. This was the answer.

Answer (score 10):

System Preferences > Bluetooth.

Find your item on the list of known devices (it has to be connected), then and control-click it, or right click on it. A context menu option will open containing a Rename option.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers don't work for me in High Sierra. In [High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205348) the trick is to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click the device in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Changing the mouse & keyboard names while using the Control button and clicking on the device worked on the MacBook Air (after the Monterey update).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

None of the options listed worked on my iMac. Here is what worked for me.

1. Connect the keyboard that you want to change the name.
2. Connect a second keyboard so you can enter the name of the keyboard
3. Go to settings, right-click on the keyboard you want to rename, and do not click the popup menu, simply leaving it open for now.
4. Turn off the keyboard that you want to rename by pressing the power button on that keyboard.
5. Using the second keyboard, select "Rename" in the pop-up menu that is still open.
6. Rename the keyboard and close the pop-up.
7. Turn the original keyboard with the new name back on and connect.

The new name is now displayed. Be sure to save this in your notes in case you  need to change the name of another Bluetooth device later on.